# Why is this function exiting early?

Tags: python-3.x, function

I have what looks to me like a completely normal function. However, for some reason, the function is exiting without executing any of the if/else statements.

```
def MainFunction():
  shapeToSolve = input("What kind of shape are you calculating?")
  print(shapeToSolve, "wtf")
  if shapeToSolve == "Square":
    solveSquare()
  elif shapeToSolve == "Circle":
    solveCircle()
  elif shapeToSolve == "Triangle":
    solveTriangle()
```

Notice the print(shapeToSolve, "wtf") block. I did this to see what's being returned from the function. Despite the fact that I have no other operation happening on `shapeToSolve()` anywhere else in the program, for some reason this prints "g wtf" to the console.

How is `shapeToSolve()` getting the letter "g" passed in as its input when the console isn't even allowing input before exiting the function?

Aside from the other functions that are called, this is the only other code in the program:

```
print("Hello! Welcome to the Geometry Calculator.")
MainFunction()
```

Comment: ı did run your code on my machine it works fine.Are you sure that you are giving the input correctly

Comment: I'm using repl.it and this makes me wonder if there's some server issue causing this. I'll have to try it on my IDE when I get home and see if I can replicate the result.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any problem. Are you sure you didn't just accidentally type `"g"` as your input?

Comment: There was definitely some error occuring on repl.it's part. I use their site to write my code and for some reason it was automatically inserting input for me last night, but today it's working just fine. Not sure what the deal was.